# For stopping times $\tau_k,\mathcal{F}_{\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}\tau_k}=\sigma(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}\mathcal{F}_{\tau_k})$?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$(\tau_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is a sequence of stopping times (taking values in $\overline{\mathbb{N}}$) for the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}.$ Let $\tau=\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*} \tau_k.$

One can prove that $\mathcal{F}_{\max(\tau_1,\tau_2)}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1} \cup \mathcal{F}_{\tau_2})$ and more generally that for $k \in \mathbb{N}^*,\mathcal{F}_{\max_{1\leq q \leq k}\tau_q}=\sigma(\bigcup_{1 \leq q \leq k}\mathcal{F}_{\tau_q}).$

Does this mean that $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}=\sigma(\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{N^*}}\mathcal{F}_{\tau_q})$ ? (Obviously $\sigma(\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{N}^*}\mathcal{F}_{\tau_q}) \subset \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$).

This question was asked several times : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307425/t-sup-n-in-mathbbnt-n-implies-mathcalf-t-sigma-bigcup-n-in-mat?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844878/a-problem-about-the-supremum-of-countable-stopping-times?noredirect=1&lq=1) without a clear proof.

We can also find particular cases of $\tau_k$: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529959/does-sigma-cup-n-0-infty-mathcalf-s-wedge-n-mathcalf-s-hold-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478216/sigma-field-of-an-increasing-sequence-of-stopping-times?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Try exercises 1.4.16 and 1.4.21 in revuz & yor.  The first is just your problem, more or less, which doesn't help, and the 2nd is galmarino's test which is useful for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Concering your question, the following facts may be useful.

(S. N. Cohen and R. J. Elliott, *Stochastic Calculus and Applications*, 2nd Ed., Springer, 2015.)
**Lemma 6.2.14** If $ \{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a nondecreasing sequence of
stoping times and $ T=\lim_n T_n $, then $ \mathcal{F}_{T-}=\bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_{T_n-} $.

**Corollary 6.2.15** Suppose $ \{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a nondecreasing sequence of stoping times and $ T=\lim_n T_n $. If $ T_n<T $ on $ \{0<T<\infty\} $
then $ \mathcal{F}_{T-}=\bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_{T_n} $.

(S. W. He et al., *Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*, Sci. Press and CRC(1992).)
**Corollary 3.5.** 6) If $ (T_n) $ is a stationary sequence of stopping times,
then
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}_{\bigvee\limits_nT_n}=\bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_{T_n}
=\Big\{ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n:A_n\in \mathcal{F}_{T_n},n\ge 1, A_kA_j=\emptyset, k\ne j. \Big\}  
\end{equation*}
Remark: $ (T_n) $ is stationary, i.e. for each $ \omega\in\Omega$ there exists a natural number $ n(\omega) $, such that $ T_n(\omega)=T_{n(\omega)}(\omega) $ when $ n\ge n(\omega) $.